# О морфонологических явлениях на стыке морфем

Tags: морфология

Какие морфонологические явления встречаются на стыке морфем слов *арготизм, либреттист, африканец, ялтинец, розоватый, бензоколонка, шестиэтажный*?

Должно встретиться одно из четырёх: интерфиксация, интерференция, усечение или чередование.

Answer (score 2):

Для решения задачи нужен **однозначный** морфемный анализ, но даже в словообразовательных словарях могут предлагаться различные виды. **Формально-структурный** разбор в этом случае более удобен (он дается в большинстве учебных материалов).

В качестве **варианта**:

**арго — арго/т/изм**. Интерфиксация: интерфикс ***Т***.

**либретто — либретт/ист**. Усечение  ***О***.

**Африка — африк/ан/ец**.   Интерфиксация: интерфикс АН.

**Ялт/ин/ск/ий — ялт/ин/ец**.   Интерфиксация: интерфикс ИН.

**Роз/ов/ый — роз/оват/ый**. Интерференция: наложение ***ОВАТ*** на ***ОВ***.

**Бензин и колонка — бенз/о/колонк/а**. Усечение  ***ИН*** и интерфиксация: интерфикс ***О***.

**шесть этажей — шест/и/этаж/н/ый.** Интерфиксация: интерфикс ***И***.

Comment: https://yarus.asu.edu.ru/?id=18#:~:text=%D0%9A%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%E2%80%93%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%2D%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%2D%D0%BA%D0%B0.

Comment: Африка — африканец, Америка - американец, Ялта — ялтинец.